# Distribution from -1 to positive infinity?

Tags: regression, distributions, data-transformation, proportion

I'm performing a regression analysis with a proportions that ranges from 0 to positive infinity, but it's currently centered on 1 (values < 1 indicate a negative relationship, values > 1indicate a positive relationship). To center the response on 0, we're simply subtracting 1 from all values, giving us a distribution of -1 to positive infinity. Is there a statistical distribution that restricts our predicted values to that range? Or any other way to achieve that?

My advisor is recommending just using general linear regression, meaning we'll get predicted values less than -1, which would be uninterpretable. I don't really like that approach, but I'm at a loss as to what my other options are.

Any citations or references would be much appreciated.

EDIT for details about the study:
The response is a ratio of two frequencies of animal captures. We have a bunch of sites split into two categories, and we count the number of animal captures per day in each category in each site. So the response is just (Capture Frequency 1 ÷ Capture Frequency 2) for each site. If CF1<CF2, we get a value less than 1. If CF1>CF2, we get a value greater than 1.

If we do a regression with our response centered on 1, it's going to predict some change in our response per unit predictor. So let's say that for some unit of a given predictor, our results show that the ratio increases by 0.3. So when the predictor equals 3, our ratio should equal 0.9 (3 x 0.3 = 0.9), meaning we expect fewer captures in our area of interest relative to the comparison area. Now when the predictor equals 4, our ratio would equal 1.2. All of sudden it's saying we have more captures in our area of interest, the opposite as before, but the value of the response is still positive. The relationship flips without the signs changing, which is just hard to interpret. It'd be much easier to interpret a negative response value as meaning fewer captures and a positive response value meaning more captures. If we center our response on 0 instead of 1, we can achieve that interpretability.

We'd like to forecast the ratio of A to B given a suite of predictors. A and B represent geographic zones. We have a big dataset with bunch of data for values of B, but no data for values of A. I went out an collected data on animal captures in both A and B. We'd like to correct our big dataset with my data (i.e., we know we have X many captures in B from this big dataset, but how many captures in A would there have been?).

Comment: If what you are examining is something like a proportion of successes to failures, which can go from 0 to positive infinity, have you considered logistic regression that was designed for just that purpose?

Comment: @EdM Ratio is probably a better word than proportion. We're using the ratio of two frequencies. I was planning on using logistic regression on the gamma distribution with a log link function, but then I realized this issue of our response being centered on 1, not 0.

Comment: Why do you need to center the response on 0? It might help to provide more details about your study, as there might be a better way to analyze these data. Please do that, including your comment about how you are analyzing a "ratio of two frequencies," by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted.

Comment: Hello welcome here. Could you please elaborate on how you exactly "center" (the formula)? That might people help to answer your question.

Comment: @EdM just edited my post!

Comment: Have you considered using a log-ratio, which is both centered at zero and symmetric in terms of effect size (i.e. log(A/B) = -log(B/A))? This builds-in the directionality sign change you're looking for with a ratio of 1 mapped to a log-ratio of 0, and makes a linear model insensitive to the baseline category (since using B/A instead of A/B merely flips the sign).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie my sense is that there are 0 values for some underlying counts/frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

> we count the number of animal captures per day in each category in each site.

If you are analyzing count data, then use a model appropriate for count data like a Poisson generalized linear model. You model the actual capture numbers, including the `site` as a categorical predictor variable in the model along with the other predictors. Then the coefficient for `site` in the model will be related to the difference in capture numbers between `siteA` and `siteB` (with a log link to capture numbers under a standard Poisson model). You could include interactions of `site` with the predictors, and include an `offset` term if there is something like site area that would necessarily be associated with capture numbers.

It sounds like you are using your study to impute missing values for `A`-type captures in a large data set with `B` values. If so, pay attention to the issues in Stef van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/). You will probably be best off using your current study to help impute several versions of the larger data set for future analysis.

Comment: Because my data is a count per day, that translates to a frequency. Poisson with an offset for the number of days to adjust for sampling effort would work, but the predicted values would be restricted between 0 and 1, and my frequencies can be greater than 1. Additionally, I need to use the ratio of frequencies, not the frequencies themselves (i.e., for every 1 capture in area B, how many captures are in area A?).

Comment: @Steve you model and can thus predict the raw counts, which can certainly be greater than 1. Translation to frequencies, if needed, can be done later. It's possible that there won't be a singe "ratio of frequencies" that describes your data; full modeling of the counts with any other covariates will provide the best chance for providing a basis for imputation to "reliably [correct] the big data set."